# iOS In App Purchases for Subscriptions and Consumables products

Tags: ios, cloud, in-app-purchase, hosted

As I understand, Store Kit API will handle storage and retrieval of history related to "Non-Consumables" products, while for "Consumables" and "Subscriptions" you have to have your own server/backend. What are the best hosted existing solutions for that kind of server (backend)? Inexpensive (or free? :-) and reliable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is not any service (that I know of) that includes the needed functionality by default.  There is more here than just hosting the files.  You need to use the included functionality to verify the receipt that is sent from the StoreKit API to your server (to ensure that it is a valid receipt):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html

So you would need to have a web application that managed this process as well as hosting the actual consumable content (in a way that made it inaccessible from the outside).  You might want to look at a Java application hosted on a solution like Elastic Beanstalk with a connection to a protected Amazon S3 account.

If this is too complex, you could also create a simple PHP application that could be run from most any web server that could also do this functionality and manage access to the S3 account's files.