# Where do you update the server on a consumable in app purchase?

Tags: ios, ios5, in-app-purchase

So I have an app that has a consumable purchase and from what I have read a little more work is involved in terms of persisting some info on the server.

What I am not clear on is where does one update the server on a sucessful purchase? Is it

- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction;

??

If it is indeed the above mentioned function, is it just a matter of making a web call and updating the server server? I am just trying to understand best practices and would appreciate any help.

much regards

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this counts as a valid answer, but you should maybe check out [this](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/) article.
The blog post is from 2010, so one could say it's rather outdated! But i think it's worth a look and the provided example (completeTransaction method implementation) should be valid also.

Getting in app purchases to work is a lot more painful than it should be actually.

Answer (score 1):

*I* did and do it in

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
...
 case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased: 
 case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
      [self sendReceiptToServerAndValidateFurther:transaction.receiptData
```

it is then only a webcall to the server-side script which can validate the receipt with itunes and update its DB/send the data

btw some server php

```
function itunes_verify2($receiptData,$sandboxed) {
    //itunes store url -- sandbox or not :)
    $itunes_storeURL = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";
    if($sandboxed == true) {
        $itunes_storeURL = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";
    }

    log_action('itunes_verify2 using ' . $itunes_storeURL);

    $post = array("receipt-data" => $receiptData ); 
    $postData = json_encode($post);

    $responseData = post_doRequest( $itunes_storeURL, $postData );
    $response = json_decode($responseData);

    if($responseArray->status == 0) {
        return "YES";
    } else {
        log_action('failed to get status ok from ' . $reponseData);
        return "NO";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a vote here for this SO question. Seems to have several examples.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178214/ios-in-app-purchase-sample-code

From what I can tell, consumables do require your own hosting, as mentioned here:
[iOS In App Purchases for Subscriptions and Consumables products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577004/ios-in-app-purchases-for-subscriptions-and-consumables-products)

I have no personal experience with consumables, only with upgrade-type IAPs, which weren't *too* painful (relatively speaking).